# Cannot get the row that contain the last day of each month

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am quite new to `SQL` and I am trying to find the row that contains the last day of each month.

`product_table` example:

```
log_date   | product_id | stock
10/30/2018 | 1001       | 59
10/29/2018 | 1002       | 100
10/28/2018 | 1003       | 2
...
9/30/2018  | 1001       | 1
9/30/2018  | 1002       | 45
```

This is my code:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_table
WHERE log_date IN 
(
    SELECT MAX(log_date)
    FROM product_table
    GROUP BY strftime('%m', log_date), strftime('%y', log_date)
)
```

Output:

```
9/9/2018    1001    28
9/9/2018    1002    94
9/9/2018    1003    29
9/9/2018    1004    89
9/9/2018    1005    3
9/9/2018    1006    46
...
```

Expected output:

```
9/30/2018   1001    28
9/30/2018   1002    94
9/30/2018   1003    29
...
8/31/2018   1001    89
8/31/2018   1002    3
...
7/31/2018   1001    46
...
```

I am working on a data file that date is a format like this: `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Should I change the date format to the normal way like `yyyy-mm-dd` because the code above returns the wrong result?

Do you guys know how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Yes you should change the format of your dates.

Comment: Ok, there was multiple issues with my answer because I realized that I originally read the question as asking for the last day of the month appearing in orders per month. Re-reading, it looks like you want to pull every row that has a max day of month. That definitely makes it a bit trickier. Looks like @forpas answer worked for you. Deleted my answer so no one had to follow the sleep-dep logic.

Comment: @Carley thank you for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your table so the dates have the format `YYYY-MM-DD` which is the only valid date format for SQLite:

```
update product_table
set log_date = 
  substr(log_date, -4) || '-' ||
  case 
    when log_date like '__/__/____' then
      substr(log_date, 1, 2) || '-' || substr(log_date, 4, 2)
    when log_date like '_/__/____' then 
      '0' || substr(log_date, 1, 1) || '-' || substr(log_date, 3, 2)
    when log_date like '__/_/____' then 
      substr(log_date, 1, 2) || '-0' || substr(log_date, 4, 1)
    when log_date like '_/_/____' then 
      '0' || substr(log_date, 1, 1) || '-0' || substr(log_date, 3, 1)
  end;
```

Then your query should work.
This is a simplification of the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_table
WHERE log_date IN 
(
    SELECT MAX(log_date)
    FROM product_table
    GROUP BY strftime('%Y%m', log_date)
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jpGTQLtuon4ANmDTVLoUXo/6).
Results:

```
| log_date   | product_id | stock |
| ---------- | ---------- | ----- |
| 2018-10-30 | 1001       | 59    |
| 2018-09-30 | 1001       | 1     |
| 2018-09-30 | 1002       | 45    |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get last day in a month based on `log_date` field, You have to use [date function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

> Compute the last day of the current month.
>
> ```
> SELECT date('now','start of month','+1 month','-1 day');
> ```

So, to get last day of current month, use:

```
SELECT T.log_date, date(substr(log_date, 6+T.noofdays, 4) || '-' || substr('00' || substr(log_date, 1, 1+T.noofdays), -2) || '-' || substr(log_date, 3+T.noofdays, 2), 'start of month', '1 month', '-1 day') AS lastdayofmonth
FROM (
  SELECT log_date, instr(log_date, '/')-2 as noofdays
  FROM product_table
) AS T;
```

[DbFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jpGTQLtuon4ANmDTVLoUXo/8)

You can also use `datetime` function in the same way.

**[EDIT]**

Accorgingly to the discusssion in comment with @forpas (Thank you for your valuable comments)...

If 'last day of month' means 'last day of month existsing in a table', then `MAX(log_date)` should do the job. But if, you want to get 'last day of month' even if there's no corresponding date in a table, above query shows how to achieve that.

Good luck!

Comment: Your code will return nulls for the OP's data: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jpGTQLtuon4ANmDTVLoUXo/0

Comment: The question is not about getting the last day of the month. The OP's query is correct. The problem is the format of the dates in the table.

Comment: I can't agree. OP wrote: "I am trying to find the row that contains the last day of each month"

Comment: Right and the query that he used is correct. So the only problem is the format of the dates.

Comment: Nope. `2018-10-29` (and so on) is not last day of month ;)

Comment: It is the last date for that month in the table if there are no rows for  2018-10-30

Comment: @forpas, Technically, there's small difference between `MAX(log_date)` and `last_day_of_month(log_date)`. I agree with other statements. Do you suggest to remove answer as is not corresponding to OP question?

Comment: I assume that either there are rows for every day in the table, or the requirement is to get the last date of each month in the table. In either case MAX(log_date) will work.